# Strange % Change results (Seeking explanation)

Tags: average, percentages

I am forecasting volumes and cannot explain a strange output we are getting from what seems to be solid equations.

To forecast

1. Take 2017 Month over Month % Changes - `(New/Old)/Old`
2. Apply 2017 monthly % changes to unknown months for 2018

For instance, to estimate August 2018 volume, we use:
 `July 2018*[((August 2017-July 2017)/July 2017)+1]`

Then, we decide to look at the yearly % change in volume (i.e. Jan 17 to Jan 18 and so on.)

Once we get to forecasted months (Aug 18 - Dec 18) we are seeing a constant yearly growth rate of `55%` even though we used monthly % changes to forecast.

**Can anyone explain the underlying math that is happening here?**

---

In photo, blues are actual, yellows are forecasted. I am just showing a few equations, but the forecast equation was used to determine all yellow cells. The % change was used to determine all yearly growths.

[image]

Comment: A percent change is normally a subtraction in the numerator, not a division. Shouldn't it be `July 2018*[((August 2017 - July 2017)/July 2017)+1]`?

Comment: Yes, updated. Thank you! That is what is shown on the excel equations. Just a typo writing it out here @AdrianKeister

Comment: Oh, I see. Nuts. I was hoping that would be the solution! Why don't you try doing a calculation by hand, to see if you've got the right formula? Then, once you've nailed that down, check to see if your spreadsheet is doing that formular correctly.

Comment: I have title checked the formulas. The percent changes are equal from month to month for 2017 to 2018. But I cannot fathom why the constant `53%` change year to year @AdrianKeister. I am wondering if there is some relationship I am missing that can explain this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forecasted volume for e.g. Aug18 is $$A18 = \frac{A17}{J17}\cdot J18$$
The yearly growth for Aug18 is $$\frac{A18-A17}{A17}= \frac{\frac{A17}{J17}\cdot J18 - A17}{A17}= \frac{J18-J17}{J17}= 53 \text {%}$$
i.e. the yearly growth for Jul18.

This will be true of all the forecasted months in 2018 as the ratio between the forecasted months in 2018 is the same as the ratio between the same months in 2017.

Comment: Frustrating and correct. It is not intuitive at all and im going to struggle explaining this to mgmt. does this mean the logic is wrong?

Comment: The logic looks fine to me, but I'm not an accountant. Perhaps there are other forecasting models which incorporate growth rates for each month from 2016 to 2017 into the forecast for growth rates in each month of 2018. In the end, a forecast is always just an educated guess, based on the available data.